# Unable to rollback parent table record if join table update fails

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've a M:N(many-to-many) relationship between `Invoice` and `Item` entities and I'm using sequelize unmanaged transaction to create an invoice by adding items in it.

The problem is, if there are any exceptions thrown while updating the join table(`invoice_items`) by adding items in it, the sequelize should roll back the parent(invoice) table transaction.

**Sequelize should not create an invoice if the join table throws an error while adding items in it.**

**Look at the code below to understand the scenario,**

```js
// start a transaction and save it into a variable
const t = await db.sequelize.transaction();  

try {
   // create new invoice
   invoice = await Invoice.create(invoice, { transaction: t });


  // adding records in join table
  await invoice.addItems([itemId], {
      through: {
          quantity: item.quantity,
          rate: item.rate
      }
  }, { transaction: t });


  await t.commit();
} catch (err) {
  await t.rollback();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` in console?  This does rollback for me but it hangs until lock timeout.  After the INSERT lines, you should see either the `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` for transaction to be completed. 

The reason of hanging is that your 2nd transaction param should be in the option object.   `addItems([itemId], { through: {}, transaction: t})`.

Comment: Thanks, Emma, you've correctly pointed out my mistake in the 2nd transaction param. I've now changed it same as shown by you `addItems([itemId], { through: {}, transaction: t})` and it has worked for me with the `ROLLBACK` status in console.